# create several excel worksheets at the same time

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am able to create Excel Worksheets in C#/VB.net using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet and add them to the Workbook and eventually open Excel as follows:

```
 Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim excel As Object = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim wb As Object = excel.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim wk1 As Object = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim wk2 As Object = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim wk3 As Object = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

    wk3.Name = "Work Sheet Three"
    wk2.Name = "Work Sheet Two"
    wk1.Name = "Work Sheet One"

    OpenWorkSheetOne()
    OpenWorkSheetTwo()
    OpenWorkSheetThree()

    excel.Visible = True
    wb.Activate()

End Sub
```

C#

```
 Private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 { 
  object excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  object wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
  object wk1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.Add();
  object wk2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.Add();
  object wk3 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.Add();
  wk3.Name = "Work Sheet Three";
  wk2.Name = "Work Sheet Two";
  wk1.Name = "Work Sheet One";

  OpenWorkSheetOne();
  OpenWorkSheetTwo();
  OpenWorkSheetThree();

  excel.Visible = true;
  wb.Activate();

   }
```

I have several Worksheets and it is taking too long to process. I want to (perhaps) process the Worksheets at the same time on different threads (I guess) and add them to the Workbook simultaneously.

How can I do that and cut the processing time?

I have googled and cannot find a suitable answer.

Comment: You may google again, I don't think it's hard to search for a tutorial about [multithread programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: Attempting to multi-thread Excel interop is seldom a good idea.  What in the OpenWorkSheet_XYZ_ methods is taking a long time.  Is there some computationally intense value determination? Or is does that code contain the immensely naive  code pattern of setting a contiguous range cell by excruciating cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library:
https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

It very simple to use :

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook()){
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
worksheet.Cell("A2").FormulaA1 = "=MID(A1, 7, 5)";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

}

Comment: OpenworksheetOne, OpenworksheetTwo and OpenWorksheetThree are functions that populate data on Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 respectively. That I can do easily. The problem is that they happen in series and are taking up too much time. Is there a way that all the three Work Sheets can be populated and added to the Workbook almost simultaneously by running the three functions?.I do not think Alexandru's solution answers my question as the WorkSheets would still be added to the Workbook one at a time.